# Is there a faster way to loop through all products in woocommcercs by distance

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website that stores latitude and longitude in custom meta fields in the product post type.

The issue I'm having is I must loop through every product to display the first 50 and this takes a very long time.

If I set 'posts_per_page' => 50 it will only show a product if there is a match in the first 50 products in the database.

How do I show the first 50 product that pass the if statement if $distance <= $distance_miles

```
$distance_miles  = 100;
$user_lat = 33.9592;
$user_long = -117.4530;
$category = 'cars';
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => -1,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $params );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
         $event_lat     = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lat',true);
         $event_long    = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lng',true);
            $earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
            $lat_1 = $event_lat;
            $lon_1 = $event_long;
            $lat_2 = $user_lat;
            $lon_2 = $user_long;
            $delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1;
            $delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1;
            $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
            $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
            $a   = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *     cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
            $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
            $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
            $distance = round($distance, 4);

          if ( $distance <= $distance_miles ) {  

              the_title();
              echo "<br>";

          }

   }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Since you have a fixed distance and have the user lat & long, would it make sense to put a `WP_Meta_Query` condition on the `WP_Query` and set a range such that lat and would would fit into a range (e.g., Lat between Z and Y and Long between W and X?

Answer (score -1):

Why not keep `posts_per_page` at -1 and then stop echoing after 50 are found like so? (See use of `$counter`)

```
$distance_miles  = 100;
$user_lat = 33.9592;
$user_long = -117.4530;
$category = 'cars';
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => -1,
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'order'               => 'DESC',
);
$counter = 0;
$the_query = new WP_Query( $params );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
         $event_lat     = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lat',true);
         $event_long    = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lng',true);
            $earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
            $lat_1 = $event_lat;
            $lon_1 = $event_long;
            $lat_2 = $user_lat;
            $lon_2 = $user_long;
            $delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1;
            $delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1;
            $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
            $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
            $a   = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *     cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
            $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
            $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
            $distance = round($distance, 4);

          if ( $distance <= $distance_miles ) {  

              the_title();
              echo "<br>";
              $counter++;
              if ($counter == 50) {
                break;
              }

          }

   }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

`break` means it will go out of the `while`-loop.

The other suggestion I have will take a certain number of products at a time (instead of all of them at once), you can set this in `$posts_per_page` variable:

```
$distance_miles  = 100;
$user_lat = 33.9592;
$user_long = -117.4530;
$category = 'cars';

$results = [];
$request_amount = 50;
$offset = 0;
$posts_per_page = 500;
while (count($results) < $request_amount) {
    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
        'offset'              => $offset,
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'order'               => 'DESC',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $params );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
             $event_lat     = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lat',true);
             $event_long    = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'prod-lng',true);
                $earth_radius = 3960.00; # in miles
                $lat_1 = $event_lat;
                $lon_1 = $event_long;
                $lat_2 = $user_lat;
                $lon_2 = $user_long;
                $delta_lat = $lat_2 - $lat_1;
                $delta_lon = $lon_2 - $lon_1;
                $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
                $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
                $a   = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) *     cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
                $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
                $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
                $distance = round($distance, 4);

              if ( $distance <= $distance_miles ) {
                  $results[] = the_title('','',false); // returns the_title instead of echo-ing it
              }

       }
    }

    // so we dont get infinite loop if less than 50 results exist
    $current_page = $the_query->get( 'paged' );
    if ( $current_page == $wp_query->max_num_pages ) {
        // You are on the last page
        break;
    }

    $offset += $posts_per_page;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

wp_reset_postdata();

echo implode("<br/>", array_slice($results, 0, $request_amount)); // reduce back to 50 if it was slightly more
```

`wp_reset_postdata();` may not be needed to be inside the while loop.

If this isn't fast enough, you may need to do the proximity search with a MYSQL query like Alex Barker mentioned.

Comment: You know, most RDBMS solutions support a way to do a proximity search on geo-coordinates. So to answer the question, stop pulling all of the results and filter in the database. See: https://clickherelabs.com/development-2/distance-searching-and-mysql/

Comment: It's not really an alternative as your answer doesn't work for the question asked.  > How do I show the first 50 product **that pass the if statement if $distance <= $distance_miles**

Comment: Are you suggesting (aside from a MYSQL solution) to pull like 50 from the database at a time and filter them until you have 50 that meet the condition? Also I fail to see how my answer doesn't work apart from the fact that it starts off with the entire amount of products. My counter is inside the if statement, so it will show the first 50 that meet the condition and then it stops?

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: @snuwerd your solution could work if I wasn't working with a large data set there could be a couple of thousand products before one is <= $distance_miles.